# Best method for reliable high volume data stream: websockets with Django Channels?

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-rest-framework

Our company built an endpoint a while back which exposes a POST endpoint to which one other company pushes A LOT of data. At peak moments there are 200+ requests per second. The stream always comes from only one client though.

I would like to make this more efficient, so to avoid the usual https overhead for every request I thought of using websockets. I've got some experience with websockets for simple websites, but so far not with continuous high volume data streams.

Our setup is based on a Python/Django stack. I could go with something different than Django, but it would be easier to keep the current setup.

So I was wondering about a couple things. First of them reliability. As far as I understand websockets are based on a `"at most once"` or `"at least once"` deliverability. In [this comment](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/492#issuecomment-274221320) I read that Django Channels are of the `"at most once"` type. That means that packets could well be missed. My question is; how can I take this into account? What are the things that influence websocket reliability? And in what order of magnitude should I think? I need to discuss our acceptance for missed records, but should I think in `0.1%`, `0.01%` or `0.0001%`?

And a more general question: are websockets a smart move in my situation? Or would you suggest a different approach? I also thought of [ZeroMQ sockets](https://zeromq.org/) (with which I have more experience), but since this is a Django setup I think websockets feel more "native".

Comment: Are the requests coming from multiple clients?

Comment: @bdoubleu - No, it's just one client. I added it to the question for more clarity.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have anything to add regarding the websockets but you could expose another endpoint that allows for posting multiple objects using [a custom ListSerializer and `bulk_create`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer). If you accumulated requests on the client side and sent them in batches every second it would reduce the overhead.

Comment: Have you profiled your code?  Do you know that the http or SSL overhead is significant?  If the client uses http2 and you proxy django on nginx using `protocol h2`, the connection _can_ be maintained and not torn down.  The SSL part of https shouldn't be that significant because modern x86 machines have AES instructions in hardware.  If you use nginx, you can use go or rust to carve out one path for speed.  In my test cases, go is ~10x faster than django and rust is ~100x faster.